# The SessionState is required by the controller but no sequential execution of consecutive requests is observed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a controller

```
[Authorize]
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Required)]
public class TestsController: Controller
{

    public JsonResult Wait(int time = 10000)
    {
           var start = DateTime.Now;
           Thread.Sleep(time);
           var end = DateTime.Now;
           var diff = (end - start);
           return Json(new
           {
               start = start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"),
               end = end.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"),
               milliseconds = diff.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#,###")
           }
    }
}
```

When I do two consecutive requests:

```
A-> action = Wait, Controller = Tests, time = 10000
B-> action = Wait, Controller = Tests, time = 100
```

B request is completed before A request. This is not what I expected since I have
decorated the TestsControllers with the

> [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Required)]

I would expect the two requests to finish in the order the were made.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The requests are made from the same Session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just decorating the controller with the `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Required)]` attribute is not enough. You should actually be writing to the session inside this action. Also if you are only reading that won't be enough too, because you could have concurrent reads from the same session. Also make sure that a session cookie is created on the client before sending those AJAX requests, for example by writing some value to the session in the controller action that served the view.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I did not write anything to the session so no session cookie was there!

Comment: Just to add my 2cents to Darin answer. I didn't knew this attribute (thks by the way :) ) and while doing some tests i found out that you don't have to write anything to the Session while executing an action in the decorated controller. Just the attribute and the fact that there's a Session is enough for the requests to be handled sequentially.